# 'LoginError' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

Tags: swift, combine, swift-composable-architecture

I'm working with Combine and composable architecture and not sure which is the root cause of the error I'm seeing.

In my login module I'm getting the following error

`'LoginError' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context`

```
public enum LoginAction: Equatable, BindableAction {
    case login(fbToken: String, fbEmail: String)
    case receivedLogin(Result<ResponseCode, LoginError>)
}
```

In my `interface` the login method is called from

```
public var getLoginToken: (LoginRequest) -> Effect<ResponseCode, LoginError>
```

In my Api module the `LoginError` is defined as

```
public enum LoginError: Equatable, LocalizedError {
    case invalidUserPassword
    case invalidServerResponse
    case urlSessionError(URLError)

    public var errorDescription: String {
        switch self {
        case .invalidUserPassword:
            return ApiClientStrings.invalidUserPassword
        case .invalidServerResponse:
            return ApiClientStrings.httpError
        case let .urlSessionError(error):
            return "\(ApiClientStrings.urlSessionError) \(error.localizedDescription)"
        }
    }
}
```

What's weird is another class in my Login module I'm calling `LoginError` and I don't get that error.

Comment: Maybe: `ModuleName.LoginError`? It's the same as having `struct Data`, you need to disembiguate between `Foundation.Data`  & `YourProject.Data` or `YourFramework.Data` Do you have another `LoginError`? Maybe through another framework?

Comment: I double checked and `LoginError` is only defined in `ApiClient` module.

Comment: @Larme thanks for the help, this got me on the right path. I went ahead and renamed `LoginError` to something else and that helped. Not sure where the conflict was unfortunately.